# Unit tests not started with Xcode 5 and jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, jenkins

I've set up jenkins on my local machine. Than I created a sample app with one failing and one succeeding unit test. When I issue the following command in the terminal

> xcodebuild  -scheme 'SampleWithTest'  -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 
>   -destination platform='iOS Simulator',OS=7.0,name='iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)'  clean test

than it clean build the project, starts the simulator and makes the tests. This is how it should work.

When I run the same command via jenkins, it clean builds the project and ends with ** TEST SUCCEEDED **  without starting the simulator or print out the test results. Jenkins just fakes, that the tests was successful.

I test it on my local machine. Nothing headless, remote, source control, slave, code signing or whatever could make any trouble.

Comment: did you find out anything_? having the same problem

Comment: Are you using the Xcode plugin for jenkins?

Comment: @quellish Yes, using Xcode Plugin for Jenkins.

Comment: If you ssh into the machine (even from the same machine) and run your xcodebuild command, do you get the same results? What if you ssh into it and run the command as the user the jenkins server runs as? Xcode and the simulator require the user to have an account that can run a window server, etc. and have developer permissions. Your jenkins user may not have all of that, or it may and the shell environment that Jenkins is using may not be set up correctly.

Comment: The unit test cases are working fine in the local Jenkins instance with same configuration as of build server but in server connected through ssh it is not launching the simulator and displaying the ** TEST SUCCEEDED ** message

Answer (score 5):

The Jenkins Xcode Plugin has not been updated to work with Xcode 5 and the XCTest framework. See [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19955). Jenkins and the Xcode Plugin do not understand XCTest output.

Additionally, Xcode 5 changed how Xcode interacts with the simulator and devices when running tests. While there is something like a "headless mode" now for the simulator, access to that functionality isn't available to the Xcode plugin. This means that in some cases, it looks to the Xcode plugin as if the tests run and exit immediately, which is not accurate.

Comment: But the question is not about xcode plugin, the problem appears when you use just xcodebuild, as zeiteisen described.

Comment: zeiteisen describes that it *does* work with xcodebuild, and in the comments elaborated that he was using the Xcode plugin for jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode is known to be pretty tricky to setup with Jenkins, Travis or other non-Apple CI solutions.

Unit Tests support is even worse so you should try using [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) instead.

Related blog entry [here](http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2013/05/07/using-travis-ci-and-xctool-to-build-and-test-ios/).